# How can I update counter on individual RecyclerView items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make a food ordering system. I am displaying 4 seperate recyclerview items with information on the different menu options, and the ability to select an up or down arrow on it to change the quantity of the specific item. The problem I am having is that when i click either arrow on one View item, it updates the item that is lowest in the list instead (e.g. If i was to click the up arrow on the top item, it would bump the counter on the bottom item up by one instead). I know there are questions with similar problems to this but none of the solutions I have found are helpful or relevant.

I have tried a few different ways of changing the value, I initially thought it would be due to using a global variable in the adaptor but i changed that and it did nothing. I believe the problem is that it is not differentiating between items and I am not sure how to make it do that.

This is my adaptor code (trimmed slightly for convenience):

```
public class MenuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MenuAdapter.MenuViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Food> foodList;
    private int userID;
    public MenuViewHolder holder;
    public int position;
    Food food;

    public MenuAdapter(Context context, List<Food> foodList, int userID) {
        this.context = context;
        this.foodList = foodList;
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_item_layout, null);
        return new MenuViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MenuViewHolder thisHolder, int thisPosition) {

        holder = thisHolder;
        position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
        holder.itemView.setId(position);

        holder.upArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int currentValue = Integer.valueOf(holder.counter.getText().toString());
                int thisOrder = BumpCountUp(currentValue);
                holder.counter.setText(String.valueOf(thisOrder));
            }
        });

        holder.downArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int currentValue = Integer.valueOf(holder.counter.getText().toString());
                if(currentValue > 0) {
                    int thisOrder = BumpCountDown(currentValue);
                    holder.counter.setText(String.valueOf(thisOrder));
                }
            }
        });


    }

    public int BumpCountUp(int count) {
        int orderCount = count + 1;
        return orderCount;
    }


    public int BumpCountDown(int count) {
        int orderCount = count - 1;
        return orderCount;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return foodList.size();
    }


    class MenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView foodImage, upArrow, downArrow;
        TextView foodName, counter, price;
        RadioButton choice1, choice2, choice3;


        public MenuViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            counter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
            upArrow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.upArrow);
            downArrow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.downArrow);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is a snippet from the activity(I am using a fragment to contain the recycleview):

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order, container, false);


        List<Food> menuList = LoginActivity.tuckBoxDB.tbDao().getAllFoods();

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        adapter = new MenuAdapter(getContext(), menuList, userID);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

I would expect this to take the view, find the counter assigned to it, get the value, bump it up/down by 1 then return the value and set the text, which is kind of what is happening, just in the wrong place.

Comment: Notify the adapter of the change with notifyItemChanged(updateIndex)

Answer (score 0):

As far as the wrong interpretation of the position of `RecyclerView` item is concerned, it generally happens when their value inside the `onBindViewHolder()` is final.

I would suggest you to remove these members variables from `MenuAdapter` class.

```
public MenuViewHolder holder;
public int position;
```

As you want to use the values of viewholder and position inside inner classes, you should create a local instance of both the variables. Inside `onBindViewHolder()` you should write:

```
MenuViewHolder holder = thisHolder;
int position = thisPosition;
```

Now use these two inside the `onBindViewHolder()` or the inner classes. These can also be final if required but the parameters of the `onBindViewHolder()` should not be final as it causes wrong interpretation of the position and viewholder item.

Comment: Thank you, I figured that making the variables final might have been part of the reason and i experimented slightly with trying to find workarounds but i didnt delve into it as much. I will test this tomorrow and let you know how it goes

Comment: thank you! completely fixed my problem, I dont know how i didnt try that earlier. Now just to tackle the issue of exporting the values to use in another activity haha